# How to add a different default background to UITableViewController when no cells exist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My `UITableViewController` has a custom subclass, and it's working great, listing Items that can be added, edited, and removed by the user. However, if there are no items, I'd like to show a background image instead of just showing an empty table view. To me, it feels a bit...strange not having cells there and I think it would be better to add some kind of background beneath the tableView.

I actually do have a custom background already set up, as such:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stripeBGGrey"]];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Is it just a case of executing a fetch request, counting the items it has, and if it has no items, then set a different BG image? And when the user adds or deletes an item, should I put this code also in `controllerWillChangeContent:` or `controllerDidChangeContent:`?

Comment: can't you add a custom subview instead of changing its background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually make this decision in my table view data source when it asks for the number of rows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    int count = [myTableViewArray count];

    tableView.hidden = (count==0);
    myImageView.hidden = (count!=0);

    return count;
}
```

Where `myImageView` has been created with a frame to match the `tableView`'s

Answer (score 1):

You can for instance add an UIImageView on top of your UITableView inside your nib file and set its visibility based on the number of rows in your table.

Something like :

```
 [_myImageView setHidden:([cells count] != 0)];
```

Then you can call this line each time the user changes the data you want to display.